# When can two .NET processes share DLL memory?

Tags: .net, windows, dll, memory-mapping

I have two ASP.NET websites that reference the same class llibrary.  Currently we publish the site with two copies of the class library.  Does this waste memory?  Does the OS know the two copies of the file are the same and so can share memory for the code sections of the DLL? If I copied it into the GAC or another shared location such that it was only one physical file, would it map less total memory?

Comment: if you are concerned about this, then something else might be wrong.

Comment: What is the size of dll if you are asking such question? And why do you tag Windows if you are talking about asp.net?

Comment: @Uzzy its actually many dlls shared, hundreds of megs worth. I was simplifying for the sake of thr question. Windows because its mainly a generic Windows question, but I included the .NET part in case it affected the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This question starts off with the wrong premise, an ASP.NET DLL doesn't contain any code. Just data, IL and the assembly manifest.  The jitter generates machine code from the IL, that code goes into the loader heap for the AppDomain.  Private bytes of the process and not shared.

Getting one copy of the machine code that's generated from the IL is possible, you have to run Ngen.exe.  It precompiles the IL and generates a native DLL, a .ni.dll that's stored in a GAC subdirectory.  That code can be shared with only one copy of it in RAM.

Comment: Loading at the preferred base address is also an important part of the puzzle.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx#S4  And Address-Space-Layout-Randomization which is implemented in newer versions of Windows and *strongly* recommended for network code will interfere with that.

Comment: @Hans Passant: In Process Explorer, I do see my .NET DLLs  loaded multiple times, from Temporary ASP.NET DLLs paths, separated by virtual path, and loaded with non-zero (often significant) WS Shareable bytes, and 0 WS Shared bytes.  That implies to me that there's something in there I could share if I stuffed it into the GAC.  And maybe even more if I NGen'd them first?

Comment: As I explained, if you want a non-zero value for shared bytes then you'll need to run ngen.exe and try again.

Comment: I'll try it, but why are there any "Shareable" bytes, if the .NET dll is all data?

Answer (score 0):

A process and an app domain has to have it loaded into memory for it to function properly. App Domains and processes are sandboxed.

Comment: Yes, but the OS has a facility to share some readonly parts of commonly loaded DLLs.  I want to know if/how to make sure I take advantage of it.